# Best money for value GPU for Core i5 9600k processor and 16GB Ram

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, performance

Which Graphics card will be the best value for money for this configuration? Suggestion will be appreciated.

1. Processor: `Core i5 9600k`
2. Motherboard: `Gigabyte Z390UD`
3. Ram: `Corsair Vengeance LPX 1x16GB 3200MHz`
4. Storage: `SSD 970 EVO Plus NVMe M.2 250GB`
5. Power Supply: `Antec 550Watt`
6. CPU Cooler: `Cryorig H7`

Comment: In general, we tend to offer per part recommendations based on your **price limit** and **intended usage** (e.g. I want to do image processing, or I want to game). Your question in it's current form is too broad. Only you know what is best value to you. With your current setup it looks like you have a lot of cash to spend and are going high spec. How about a RTX 2080 TI?

Comment: I am currently unable to spend more than $350 right now.

Comment: Unless RubyJunk's assumptions about your criteria for best value are sufficient, what are you planning to use this setup for? Do you want to maximize performance @ $350 or minimize price?

Comment: I want maximum performance @ $350. Your suggestion will be appreciated. :)

Comment: I think it would make far more sense if we give you a complete build rather than specific graphic card recommendations. Can you give us an overall budget, intended use case (and, if gaming, what games), and if you're willing to buy used?

Comment: Brother, I have already built that PC with the mentioned configuration. That's why I was asking about only GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by https://gpu.userbenchmark.com, calculating "value" with the following equation:

`("Effective 3D Speed" / Price in Dollars)` and assuming your price bracket is at most $500, which seems to be about 2/3 of the cost of your computer, and assuming that ray tracing hardware is unimportant, the **AMD RX 5700 XT** appears to be your best "value" options.

Compare the "value" of the **RX 5700 XT** to other popular graphics cards:

---

- RX 580 - **0.39**
- RX 5700 XT - **0.36**
- RX 5700 - **0.36**
- GTX 1660 Ti - **0.34**
- RTX 2060 SUPER - **0.29**
- RTX 2070 SUPER - **0.28**
- RTX 2080 SUPER - **0.23**
- RTX 2080 Ti - **0.19**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am planning to buy RTX 2060 Super.